# Trying to assign arrays to an object and assign it a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am very new to programming. Maybe I'm not thinking it right...
Here is the situation:

I have an SVG Canada map (with 12 provinces, each one has an ID).
I want to give each province a minimum age, and on click of each province, I want to output the age in the console.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    let province = {
    manitoba:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $('#manitoba')
    },
    yukon:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#yukon")
    },
    alberta:{
        age:"18",
        selector: $("#alberta")
    },
    saskatchewan:{
        age:"9",
        selector: $("#saskatchewan")
    },
    ipe:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#ipe")
    },
    nb:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#nb")
    },
    ontario:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#ontario")
    },
    quebec:{
        age:"21",
        selector: $("#quebec")
    },
    novaScotia:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#novaScotia")
    },
    bc:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#bc")
    },
    northwest:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#northwest")
    },
    newfoundland:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#newfoundland")
    },
    nunavut:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#nunavut")
    }
}

$("#manitoba").click(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).age);
});
```

And returns `undefined`.

#### UPDATE

Here is the HTML (I only pasted 2 of the provinces since it's an SVG and it's HUGE)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- <ul>
            <li id="qcElem">quebec</li>
            <li id="onAge">ontario</li>
            <li id="bcAge">BC</li>
        </ul> -->
            <li value="18">Qc</li>
            <li value="19">On</li>
            <li value="21">Bc</li>

            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1200 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1200 800;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#3C806F;}
    .st1{fill:#6CB494;}
    .st2{fill:#29614F;}
    .st3{display:none;}
    .st4{display:inline;}
    .st5{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st6{fill:#FBC733;}
    .st7{fill:#F29451;}
    .st8{fill:#ED717D;}
    .st9{fill:#EA5845;}
</style>
<polygon value="19" id="manitoba" class="st0" points="545.45,593.05 558.91,577.26 568.96,563.06 605.47,507.95 596.12,506.69 
    586.88,503.14 577.36,505.64 572.59,508 569.03,510.11 567.6,509.27 564.63,511.59 567.35,502.38 562.82,492.28 558.28,481.5 
    555.98,476.64 553.85,477.05 550.88,476.77 546.8,479.94 546.09,486.39 545.98,479.08 544.3,477.56 542.77,475.64 541.31,475.06 
    538.55,471.95 538.98,453.86 483.95,455.65 468.27,455.4 465.89,538.34 470.3,670.07 489.74,670.22 523.66,669.56 549.17,668.29 
    549.9,667.17 549.57,660.86 545.33,596.27 "/>
<polygon value="19" id="yukon" class="st0" points="211.02,399.68 261.31,419.06 259.94,417.53 260.51,416.49 260.39,414.67 260.31,411.5 
    260.79,409.77 259.95,408.62 259.26,405.76 260.16,403.19 259.27,398.71 257.51,400.16 255.54,399.72 253.69,400.12 249.11,396.57 
    247.38,397.17 247.02,396.14 245.96,396.92 243.75,396.35 240.83,395.78 241.75,390.4 240.72,389.29 241.58,388.72 242.39,387.26 
    242.86,381.47 240.17,379.68 239.02,377.24 238.62,373.82 237.77,371.06 236.01,365.77 234.7,366.18 234.38,365.32 232.21,363.77 
    233.31,359.67 233.92,357.96 235.11,357.44 234.48,355.98 233.86,351.08 234.47,348.63 236.67,346.14 235.34,344.64 235.53,342.92 
    235,341.13 234.8,340.22 236.47,339.63 238.83,337.32 238.32,334.74 238.38,333.8 237.52,333.32 237.82,332.25 238.73,331.08 
    236.35,325.44 236.93,320.57 235.58,316.34 232.47,316.19 233.72,314.47 233.38,312.42 232.97,309.46 232.09,307.83 230.78,306.83 
    231.47,305.38 233.12,303.72 234.47,303.08 234.25,301.99 233.95,301.11 234.3,299.87 233.1,298.98 235.5,297.97 238.49,296.22 
    241.25,290.8 241.11,288.49 243.47,287.03 242.45,286.08 241.69,285.74 238.85,286.41 240.02,284.77 237.67,284.01 234.95,283.26 
    235.89,280.9 237.88,279 237.28,277.29 239.67,274.87 241.18,270.26 242.29,267.82 242.4,264.8 233.07,259.83 229.34,257.19 
    232.11,253.76 233.99,250.35 235.07,248.26 234.89,246.12 237.97,241.13 247.87,226.65 246.26,225.86 245.02,223.86 242.94,220.69 
    240.22,212.97 239.83,208.53 237.75,205.1 234.63,202.76 231.88,199.88 186.76,257.73 142.97,317.27 124.47,343.52 124.37,347.15 
    127.18,348.1 128.81,351.11 131.35,351.82 134.78,352.2 137.89,353.91 135.55,356.5 134.4,359.62 161.09,375.21 "/>

</svg>

    </div>
    <form onSubmit="toutCa(); return false;">
        <input type="text" id="inputtedAge">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <div id="slider"></div>

    <p>click me</p>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use: `$("#manitoba").click(function(event) {
  console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});`.

Comment: Can you share the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns `undefined` because the key `age` does not exist in a `DOM`
I think what you are looking for is :

```js
$("#manitoba").click(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

### Updated solution

The new code would be :

```js
let province = {
    manitoba:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $('#manitoba')
    },
    yukon:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#yukon")
    },
    alberta:{
        age:"18",
        selector: $("#alberta")
    },
    saskatchewan:{
        age:"9",
        selector: $("#saskatchewan")
    },
    ipe:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#ipe")
    },
    nb:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#nb")
    },
    ontario:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#ontario")
    },
    quebec:{
        age:"21",
        selector: $("#quebec")
    },
    novaScotia:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#novaScotia")
    },
    bc:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#bc")
    },
    northwest:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#northwest")
    },
    newfoundland:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#newfoundland")
    },
    nunavut:{
        age:"19",
        selector: $("#nunavut")
    }
}

$("#Layer_1").on("click", "polygon",function(event) {
    console.log(province[$(this).attr("id")].age);
});
```

After all you need to check if the key exists in the object for avoid errors.

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/Lyu54vjg/

Comment: ok i understand. However, i need to output the age i defined in each province... i basically wanted to create an object that had the 12 provinces, and each province has its "age" defined. and i wanted to be able to interact with the DOM... because i'm not looking to console log the ID, but the age of that given province... i will try with data-attributes, but isn't there a way to do this with objects?

Comment: @JoMourad Can you update your question with the `HTML` you have right now?

Answer (score 1):

I would use data-attributes instead of the JS object

```js
//jQuery Version with ES5

$('.province').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).data('age'))
})

//vanilla JS with ES6

document.querySelectorAll('.province').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.info(e.currentTarget.dataset.age)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="province" data-age='19'>manitoba</div>
<div class="province" data-age='18'>alberta</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that was my next step!